# How can I draw crisp per-pixel images with OpenGL ES on Android?

Tags: android, java, opengl-es2

I have made many Android applications and games in Java before, however I am very new to OpenGL ES. Using guides online, I have made simple things in OpenGL ES, including a simple triangle and a cube.

I would like to make a 2D game with OpenGL ES, but what I've been doing isn't working quite so well, as the images I draw aren't to scale, and no matter what guide I use, the image is always choppy and not the right size (I'm debugging on my Nexus S).

How can I draw crisp, HD images to the screen with GL ES?

Here is an example of what happens when I try to do it:
[image]

And the actual image: [image]

Here is how my texture is created:

```
//get id
int id = -1;
gl.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
id = texture[0];

//get bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

//parameters
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
        GL10.GL_REPLACE);

GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

//crop image
mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
mCropWorkspace[1] = height;
mCropWorkspace[2] = width;
mCropWorkspace[3] = -height;
((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! As you can see in the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As such you tend to get the best, most-focused answers from our users if you only post a single actual question per "topic." I've edited your question to remove your query about creating a game loop as it's largely unrelated to your question about crisp sprites -- you should instead hit the "Ask A Question" button to create a new topic about your game loop question.

Comment: That said, it would probably help if you provided at least a brief overview of the method by which you're currently rendering images to the screen and/or a screenshot of the artifacts you're seeing.

Comment: @Josh: Thank you for your insightful words. I have added images of the problem, and how I'm currently creating textures.

Comment: I suggest showing the code which actually draws the texture. What you've got doesn't look unreasonable, but it's not the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR`.

`gl.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of parameters you need to set on the texture, the first one is to tell OpenGL what to do if the texture need to be shrunk or magnified to match the rendered image. For a blurred image you should utilize another one. For a crisp and clean rendering image then other. For more details, followings #

- `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` : If the texture is smaller it needs to be
  magnified that is done with the magnification function
- `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` : If the texture needs to be scaled down
  using the minification function
- `GL_LINEAR` : For a blurred image
- `GL_NEAREST` : For a crisp and clean rendering image

Utilize **`GL_NEAREST`**

> gl.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is called "pixel perfect texture mapping".

You need to call

```
gl.glOrthof(0, displayWidth, 0 , displayHeight, 0.0f, 100.0f);
```

in your initialization function.
This will set 1 OpenGL unit equals to 1 pixel. OpenGL coordinates will be (0,0) for the top-left angle and (width, height) for the bottom-right angle.